# Why does the django request.query_params return undefined?

Tags: python, typescript, django-rest-framework, next.js, query-string

In `next.js` index page, I have this request in `getServerSideProps`:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  async (context) => {
    const { store, query } = context;
    if (!query.page) {
      query.page = "1";
    }
    if (!query.keyword) {
      query.keyword = "";
    }
    console.log("query in serverSide", query);
    // this logs : { page: '1', keyword: '' }
    store.dispatch(
      fetchProductsStart(`keyword=${query["keyword"]}&page=${query["page"]}`)
    );
    store.dispatch(END);
    await (store as SagaStore).sagaTask.toPromise();
    const state = store.getState();
    const productListState = state.productList ? state.productList : null;
    return { props: { productListState } };
  }
);
```

This works with no error. However in another page, if I send the same request inside `useEffect` with valid request parameters I am getting error:

```js
let keyword = Router.router?.query.keyword as string;
let queryPage = Router.router?.query.page as string;

useEffect(() => {
    const query = Router?.router?.query;
    console.log("query", query);
    // this logs: {keyword: "", page: "1"}
    dispatch(fetchProductsStart(`keyword=${keyword}&page=${queryPage}`));
    if (!userInfo?.isAdmin) {
      Router.push("/login");
    }
  }, [dispatch, userInfo]);
```

In both cases I am sending valid structure of query parameters. In the second case, for some reson django does receive query parameters as undefined. Here is django code:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def getProducts(request):
    query_params=request.query_params
    print("query_params",query_params)
    keyword = request.query_params.get("keyword")
    if keyword==None:
        keyword=""
    print("query",request.query_params.get("keyword"))
    products=Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=keyword)
    print("products",products)
    # We want to paginate filtered results
    page=request.query_params.get("page")
    print("page",page)
    paginator=Paginator(products,4)
    try:
        products=paginator.page(page)
    # when we first visit the page,there is no query set
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        products=paginator.page(1)
    # if user sends high number
    except EmptyPage:
        products=paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    if page==None:
        page=1
    page=int(page)
    serializer=ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response({'products':serializer.data, 'page':page, 'pages':paginator.num_pages})
```

When I  `print("query_params",query_params)`, this is what I get:

`<QueryDict: {'keyword': ['undefined'], 'page': ['undefined']}>`

Since page is undefined, `page=int(page)` is throwing this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'undefined'

But If page is not defined, I assigned it to be 1:

```
# if not page: I tried this too
if page==None:
        page=1
print("page",page)
```

when I print "page" right after "if statement", I get "page" undefined. It should be 1.

Comment: What is a `queryPage` in`dispatch(fetchProductsStart(\`keyword=${keyword}&page=${queryPage}\`));`, are you sure it is valid? In the first example, you are using `page`

Comment: @nenadp I assigned page to be 1, if it is undefined, if page==None:
        page=1
print("page",page), why do I get "page" undefined. Should'nt it be 1

Comment: Shouldn't your `dispatch` call inside `useEffect` be ``dispatch(fetchProductsStart(`keyword=${query.keyword}&page=${query.page}`));`` instead? OR are you defining `keyword` and `queryPage` elsewhere outside the `useEffect`?

Comment: @juliomalves  I defined them outside useEffect. I updated the question. The thing that makes more confused is `if page==None:
        page=1` inside django. I m saying if page is None, assign it to 1 but I still get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In querydict, page and keyword is undefined. so you can't compare them with None.
you should write condition like this:

```
if page or page is None:
   page = 1
```